# How to get required type of files from a directory and required content using node js?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, xml

Am developing node js application to extract some content alone from XML or HTML file. Am using a windows machine. Some Npm packages are working only in apple or Linux machine, i could not use it. I have tried to get the particular files alone from a directory since that directory contains multiple files.

For example, files names are project1.abi.xml, project1.xbi.xml, project2.abi.xml, project2.xbi.xml, new\xxcover.html.

First of all, i wish to get *.abi.xml files alone. Secondly, i wish to get *.xbi.xml alone.  Third, *cover.html. But, i can get all the files in a directory using readdirSync. And then am checking whether the looping file is required one and then perform the function i need.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'D:\\Work\\Testing\\logs\\';
var files = fs.readdirSync(path);
var len;
for (index = 0, len = files.length; index < len; index++) {
    if (files[index].indexOf('xbi.xml') !== -1) {        
          console.log(path+files[index]); 
    }
}
```

To avoid this, is there any way to get the particular type of files from a directory before looping? Could anyone please guide me on this?

Also, am trying to get the "Total Warnings" count(216) from a html file using Regular Expression in node js. Am getting the result as undefined. Below is my code. Could you please point out me where i have made mistake to correct it?

**HTML Content**

```
<body>
<h1>2017 report</h1>
<dl>
<dt>Source Directory:</dt>
<dd>F:\ion\ket\Automation\App</dd>
    <dt>Settings File:</dt>
    <dd>F:\ion\ket\Automation\App\Net.json, F:\ion\ket\Automation\App\Net.Debug.json</dd>
    <dt>Processed Files:</dt>
    <dd>30</dd>
    <dt>Files with Warnings:</dt>
    <dd>0</dd>
    <dt>Total Warnings:</dt>
    <dd>216</dd>
</dl>
```

**Code:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'C:\\Users\\akil\\Desktop\\App.Net.html';
var files = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8');
var re = new RegExp('/<dt>Total Warnings:</dt>\s+<dd>(?![\s\S]*</dd>)/');
var r  = files.match(re);
if (r)
    console.log(r[1]);
console.log(r);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the files by extension, you could try a **array.filter** function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Example

```
var allFiles = fs.readdirSync(path);
var filteredFiles = allFiles.filter(function(value) {
    var extension = 'xbi.xml';
    return value.endsWith(extension);
});
```

---

Concerning your **regex** problem:

- As @siam pointed out correctly, the JavaScript *RegEx* needs the backslash **escaped** as `\\`
- I assume, you want to find a 'Total Warnings' count as a number. So I would suggest looking for a series of digits (**\d***) instead.

This regex should match your example:

```
var re = new RegExp('<dt>Total Warnings:</dt>\\s+<dd>\\d*</dd>');
                                                     ^
```

Does this help?

Comment: Interesting. In my editor, the regex matches the example. In node it still returns `null`.

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg try adding double backslash ' \\ ' before `s` and `d`

Comment: Thx, @siam. In the end it was *that* one ;-)

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg, Thanks. Finally worked. var re = new RegExp('<dt>Total Warnings:</dt>\\s+<dd>(.*)</dd>');

Comment: @siam, Thanks. Finally worked. var re = new RegExp('<dt>Total Warnings:</dt>\\s+<dd>(.*)</dd>');

Comment: @VADIVELNATARAJANuser2505309, good to hear that. Just be careful, when you use dot __(.*)__. This pattern matches any character except newline (\n). So you have to check for valid values in your program.

If my answer was helpful, please feel free and mark it as "accepted" ;)